# How to measure the tilt angle of a rectangle if you know positions of the four corners?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, computational-geometry

I have an apparatus in which I have a rectangular (nearly square) object hanging straight But there is a bit of tilt in it. I can measure the four corners of this rectangular object. How can I measure the tilt angle now?

I have seen somewhere that I can do it by using the cross product between two points but I am not really sure and not getting any useful material online. Sorry, its very simple but I am really confused.

Comment: add image ... is it 2D or 3D? in 2D you just take one side of the rectangle substract theses 2 points and do atan2 on it .... `ang = atan2(y1-y0,x1-x0)`  this will give you angle between x axis and the side you chose. However what do you mean by tilt is unknown (you did not provide enough info) so it might be different angle ...

Comment: Hi, it is a 3D thing as it is hanging. Think about a robotic gripper holding a glass slide that has a rectangular stamp on it. I know the positions (x,y,z) of all the corners of that stamp. Now all four corners are not precisely on the same z-level as there is a tilt in the glass slide. My question is: how can I find that tilt if I know the four corners of that stamp on the glass slide? I want to find the tilt on the stamp.

Comment: OK so you have planar rectangle arbitrary oriented in 3D space with known corners in 3D now what do you consider a tilt angle? angle between camera view axis (z) and normal to the rectangle plane? or rotation of the rectangle (inside it plane) against some known axis? or what? is it signed or absolute value suffice?

Comment: Hi, yes my tilt angle is the angle made by this hanging object with a known axis.

Comment: Please find a rough sketch of what I was talking about.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1R5adI1hmZrqc7WFafoH_eXcYxXJ0AneF/view?usp=sharing

Comment: your sketch is still private without permissions... if you paste it on imgur it can be directly added to your question as this site uses it too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Defining X is left-right directional axis, this problem can be considered as 2D problem (on Y-Z plane).

See figure below.

[image]

`N_yz` is the vector only has y and z component of the normal of the square. i.e. if the normal is `(nx,ny,nz)`, `N_yz = (0,ny,nz)`.

Now, you can calculate the tilt angle from innerproduct or crossproduct   between this `N_yz` and Z(or Y) axis.